# Efficiency when ranking dates using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have data on dates of visits and personal ids:

```
n     <- 1e6 
set.seed(42L)
DT <- data.table(id = sample(1:37000, n, replace=TRUE),
                 date = as.Date("1963-07-13", "%Y-%m-%d")
                 - sample(1:9000, n, replace=TRUE))
```

I'm adding a variable that ranks the visits for each person. Visit #1, #2, etc. If I can't differentiate between two visits they can be ranked in any (consistent) way.

After my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38357093/4552295) (on efficiency) I realised I should learn how to use `data.table`. So my current solution is with data.table -- the only problem is the command takes few seconds to run.

```
> system.time(DT[, visit.n := rank(date, ties.method="first"), by = id]
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   4.42    0.02    4.44
```

I wonder if I'm doing something "wrong" or just need to be patient and move on.

Comment: Try `setkey(DT, date); system.time(DT[, visit.n := 1:.N, by=id])`

Comment: Assuming you like your jumbled dates as they are, you can just use order(date) in i to sort only for the purpose of making the new col. And if you care about performance, you might consider integer storage formats for dates, so `system.time(DT[, date := as.IDate(date)][order(date), visit.n := 1:.N])` I see this taking ~ half the time of Martin's setkey. Also note that an author of the package says "In most cases therefore, there shouldn't be a need to set keys anymore." http://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/

Comment: Interesting. But your line of code does not yield the desired output, right? When adding `by=id` (so the output is correct), the performance effort again doubles...

Comment: when `by=id` it does seem to work fine, and indeed cut the computing time in half when using `as.IDate()`!

Comment: @Martin D'oh. Yeah, I initially had `rowid(id)` before realizing that was devel-only, and then edited wrongly to `1:.N` instead of `1:.N, by=id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from my comment:

As @Frank pointed out, `setkey` is not necessary. Just using `order(date)` is sufficient to rank the dates. I also incorporated his point of saving the dates as integers.

```
system.time({
  DT[, date := as.IDate(date)][order(date), visit.n := 1:.N, by=id]
}) 

   user      system     elapsed
  0.126       0.005       0.132
```

Comment: Great improvement! But I also tried 'setkey(DT, id)' and that was even faster.

Comment: The setkey belongs inside the timing; the 1:.N is now available in a rowid(id) function; and setkey is rarely necessary (see comment above). Just fyi. Oh, I guess rowid is still only in the devel version.

Comment: how does `setorder(DT, date)[, visit.n := 1:.N, by = id]` compare?